# Changing the list of items doesn't rerender the component when using react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using `react-beautiful-dnd` to let the user choose the options using drag and drop.

However, the component doesn't seem to re-render when the order of the options is changed. (I've tried console logging it, and it appears to have changed.)

This is the `onDragEnd` method:

```
const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const { source, destination } = result;

    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    if (source.index === destination.index) {
      return;
    }

    let items = [...list];
    const [removed] = items.splice(source.index, 1);
    items.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);

    setList([...items]);
  };
```

All the code can be found in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-example-kiqu7y?file=/src/OptionalCoursesContainer.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering `optionalCourses` in the DND but you are updating the list state.
You should render the `list` instead.

```
return (
    <div className={componentClassName}>
      <span className={`${componentClassName}__title`}>{groupTitle}</span>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId={groupId}>
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              className={`${componentClassName}__list`}
            >
              

>  {list.map((optionalCourse, index) => {
>                      return <OptionalCourseCard key={index} {...optionalCourse} />;

              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I've literally tried finding the bug for a few days... Thanks:)